# How to show search query from a jtextfield to a jtable from mysql table with using Where Clause query

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, resultset

I'm trying to show search result from mysql table through a jtextfield, but after I clicked the button it doesn't show in jtable I wonder why, please help me to solve this error, thanks :)

Button Code on MouseCLicked :

```
private void btn_cariMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        if(!inp_npm.getText().isEmpty()){
            show_item_in_searchTbl();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill the empty text!");
        }
    }

 public void show_item_in_searchTbl(){
        try{
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zazu_school","root",""); 
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT NPM FROM daftar_mahasiswa WHERE NPM LIKE '%" + inp_npm.getText() + "%'";
            ResultSet rs;
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)src_mhs_tbl.getModel();
            while(rs.next()){
                Object[] kolom = new Object[3];
                kolom[0] = rs.getInt("ID");;
                kolom[1] = rs.getString("Nama");
                kolom[2] = rs.getString("NPM");
                kolom[3] = rs.getString("Jurusan");

                model.addRow(kolom);
            }
            conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException ex){

        }
    }
```

[the image of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maern.png)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

The error is happening when you call the following :

```
kolom[0] = rs.getInt("ID");
```

However, your Select statement is :

```
        String query = "SELECT NPM FROM daftar_mahasiswa WHERE NPM LIKE '%" + inp_npm.getText() + "%'";
```

ie. your getInt is attempting to get a value for a column that was never selected, so is not in the ResultSet.

The defined behaviour for getInt is to therefore throw a `SQLException`, which you catch but don't log it or anything.

Solution is to :

1) modify your SELECT to retrieve all the columns

2) Add some logging, etc to properly handle SQLException

3) The clause `'%" + inp_npm.getText() + "%'"` is opening your Select statement to SQL Injection attacks, so instead generate your statement using PreparedStatement.

Comment: thanks, for the solution, I have found another method but thanks for the answer.

Comment: *"I have found another method"* Congratulations on subtracting from the sum total of human knowledge. If you intend to *add* to the sum total of human knowledge, enter an answer describing the solution used.